# How do I fill data from MySQL database into a treeview in python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, treeview

I am sorry if I have posted this in the wrong section, I am new to stackoverflow and I did search for similar topics but didn't get what I needed.

So what I'm trying to do is, getting information of a table from mysql database in the form: ((1, google, username1, password1), (2, facebook, username2, password2) ...)

And fill that in the treeview which has 4 columns **Website, Username, Password** which looks like:[image: treeview columns]

What I have tried is:

```
#find password
def find_password(selection):
#remove the frame if it already exists
for child in frame.winfo_children():
    child.destroy()

#to fill tree with tuples
def show_table(table):
    for x in table:
        tree.insert("", 0, text=x)


#button1 function
def btn_input_one(text1): 

    text_input = text1.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='suryansh',user='suryansh',password='suryansh')
    if connection.is_connected():
        cursor = connection.cursor(buffered = True)
        cursor.execute("select database();")


        #sql queries
        create_table_query = "select * from " + text_input
        cursor = connection.cursor(buffered = True)
        result = cursor.execute(create_table_query)
        table = cursor.fetchall()
        show_table(table)
```

That is what I tried and this is what I got:
[image: result of the above]

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me with this and the solution is:

```
for x in table:
    tree.insert("", "end", text=x[1], values=(x[2], x[3]))
```

That is how you fill the other columns other than the default ones :D